# Why does X11 break inside Docker container when the container connects to VPN?

Tags: windows, docker, xorg, vcxsrv, openconnect

My host computer is Windows 10.
My objective is to make docker containers that connect to VPNs inside the container. I do this so that I don't have to have my entire host computer on the VPN.

I use ubuntu docker containers that connect, with openconnect, to anyconnect protocol; I have two different containers that connect to two different organizations' VPNs.

Both containers work with X11 to my vcxsrv, e.g. I can see xeyes and even vscode. However, only one will work after I connect it to a VPN.

The container can still connect to websites, ping google, etc. But I have tried setting the DISPLAY variable to the new IPv4 private VPN address, no luck. xeyes does not appear. xeyes runs until I Ctrl+C, but xeyes does not appear on vcxsrv

How can I get X11 to work inside docker container while connected to VPN?
My host is NOT connected to VPN. Only the containers have VPNs inside them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use `vpn-slice` inside the docker container when connecting to VPN:

```bash
openconnect -b -v --protocol=anyconnect \
    # some cert files, key files, etc... whatever you normally use
    vpn.myorganization.com \
    -s 'vpn-slice --prevent-idle-timeout mymachine.myorganization.com'
```

thus only requests and connections destined for `mymachine.myorganization.com` are put through the VPN. In order to use this, vpn-slice must be installed with pip